# Python merging lists

Tags: python

```
mylists = [ [1,3,5,7], [2,4,7,8], [11,15], [20] ]
import time
def timeit(f):
    def wrapper(*args, **kw):
        t = time.time()
        res = f(*args, **kw)
        print "%s took %s" % (f.func_name, time.time() - t)
        return res

    return wrapper

# merge two given lists
def merge(l, r):
    if len(l) == 0:
        return r

    if len(r) == 0:
        return l

    if l[0] <= r[0]:
        return [l[0]] + merge(l[1:], r)
    else:
        return [r[0]] + merge(l, r[1:])

def merge2(x,y):
    if len(x) == 0:
        return y
    if len(y) == 0:
        return x

    #pop the lower one between the two biggest items
    last = y.pop() if x[-1] < y[-1] else x.pop()

    merged = merge2(x,y)
    merged.append(last)

    return merged

def merge3(xs, ys):
    ms = []
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while i < len(xs) and j < len(ys):
        if xs[i] <= ys[j]:
            ms.append(xs[i])
            i = i + 1
        else:
            ms.append(ys[j])
            j = j + 1 
    while i < len(xs) and j == len(ys):
        ms.append(xs[i])
        i = i + 1

    while i == len(xs) and j < len(ys):
        ms.append(xs[i])
        j = j + 1

    return ms

# divide and conquer
def lmerge(lists, m):
    if len(lists) <= 1:
        return lists

    mid = len(lists) / 2

    llists = lmerge(lists[:mid], m)
    rlists = lmerge(lists[mid:], m)

    # the bottom merge will have a list of list
    if isinstance(llists[0], list):
        llists = llists[0]
    if isinstance(rlists[0], list):
        rlists = rlists[0]

    return m(llists, rlists)

@timeit
def a():
    print lmerge(mylists, merge)

@timeit
def b():
    print lmerge(mylists, merge2)

@timeit
def c():
    print lmerge(mylists, merge3)

@timeit
def d():
    print sorted(reduce(lambda x,y: x + y, mylists))


a()
b()
c()
d()
```

---

```
antz@antz-90X3A:~/python/algo$ python addlists.py 
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 11, 15, 20]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 11, 15, 20]
a took 7.00950622559e-05
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 11, 15, 20]
b took 6.103515625e-05
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "addlists.py", line 101, in <module>
    c()
  File "addlists.py", line 13, in wrapper
    res = f(*args, **kw)
  File "addlists.py", line 97, in c
    print lmerge(mylists, merge3)
  File "addlists.py", line 82, in lmerge
    if isinstance(rlists[0], list):
IndexError: list index out of range
antz@antz-90X3A:~/python/algo$
```

kinda confused why its raising and index error for merge3?

merge, merge2, merge3 should have the same output (at least in my mind) so i dont understand why its raising an IndexError because it works for merge and merge2

EDIT: Can I also have a better merge algorithm if there is one?

Comment: Would be easier to answer if you narrowed down where the program went wrong and provided sample input for those few functions.

Comment: ^ we don't need the whole script, just anything related to the issue

Comment: @NewWorld ok yeah i added it

Comment: @RUJordan the point of the question is the other merges are the same as merge3 yet its raising an error at merge3 so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed something this is easily done:

```
mylists = [ [1,3,5,7], [2,4,7,8], [11,15], [20] ]
newlist = []
for elem in mylists:
    newlist.extend(elem)
newlist = sorted(newlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a misstake at the end of `merge3()`.
If `i == len(xs)` than `ms.append(xs[i])` will always fail becaus `xs[i]` is out of range.

```
while i == len(xs) and j < len(ys):
    #ms.append(xs[i]) # Possibly wrong.
    ms.append(ys[j]) # I think that is what you want instead.
    ....
```

You wont get index out of range errors anymore and your algorithm should work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of issues here. Debugging is a rough thing to do, especially when it's your own code. My first suggestion to you is to start putting print statements throughout your code, see where and what the problem is. If you expect something like 'mylists' to always look the same, check it out and see whether it ever changes.

That being said here's what's going on:

My first suggestions would be to check out what happens to 'mylists' in each merge. Right now you think the issue is in merge3. But really there's something funky going on before you get to that point.

You're using a recursive call to merge2 in merge2. Which is awesome, because recursion is awesome. But what happens when you reach the end of either list? What is happening to the lists as they are passed into the function? If merge2 reaches the end of x or y it returns either x or y. But what is x or y? Well they are the original list you passed into python that has been **modified** over time. In merge2 you are actually changing the lists you pass in. But, you might say, the same thing happens when I make a copy of the lists! Well yes, let's make a copy of the lists using standard temp_lists = list(mylist) and check out the ids of everything you passed in. Comment out a(), c() and d() and change b() to look like this and check it out:

```
@timeit
def b():
    temp_lists = []
    temp_lists = list(mylists)  #making our copy here
    print "in b"
    print "id of temp_lists is: ", id(temp_lists)
    print "id of mylists is: ", id(mylists)
    print "id of temp_lists[0] is: ", id(temp_lists[0])
    print "id of mylists[0] is: ", id(mylists[0])
    print lmerge(temp_lists, merge2)
    print "after b"
    print "id of temp_lists[0] is: ", id(temp_lists[0])
    print "id of mylists[0] is: ", id(mylists[0])
```

The output should look like:

```
$ python merge_play.py 
in b
id of temp_lists is:  140392743662368
id of mylists is:  140392743662872
id of temp_lists[0] is:  140392743662512
id of mylists[0] is:  140392743662512
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 7, 8, 11, 15, 20]
after b
id of temp_lists[0] is:  140392743662512
id of mylists[0] is:  140392743662512
b took 0.000180959701538
```

Notice that the ids of temp_list and mylist are different but the ids of temp_list[0] and mylist[0] are the same. That means as you are popping stuff off of each list to merge them, you are modifying the original lists. There are a couple of ways to fix this. Check out copy.deepcopy() or, depending on the context of this question, write your own method to recursively copy lists.

You have other issues(For example what happens if you pass in an empty list in my lists?) but, right now, your issue lies in how you are handling the lists you pass into merge2.